# Java Server Socket with Client in C

Tags: java, c++, sockets

I have written the server socket code in java. The relevant lines are:

```
byte[] bRecieved = new byte[440] ;
1int i =in.read(bRecieved);
Arrays.toString(bRecieved);
```

This works fine if the client is written in java

```
 byte[] bSend = {1,2,3,4};
 DataOutputStream out =
                       new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
 out.write(bSend);
```

But the Client is written in C++. The code for sending is:

```
if (client.connect(serverIP, serverPort)) {
   String msg="Hello Server";//Message to be sent
    client.println(msg);//send the message
}
```

My question is , how do I communicate with the java server wanting bytes? The connection is successful and bytes are printed on the server console. But they are not "Hello Server". Do I have to iterate through the bytes and interpret them as chars? Chars and int are 1 byte in c++.

Please clarify this situation if possible.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The C++ program needs its buffer flushed.  Read about line buffering and flush.

Comment: Also, `int` is not one byte in C++. It's actually platform specific, though ALMOST everything you're probably going to touch has an `int` as 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

What library are you using for your C++ sockets?

You might try flushing the stream?

Answer (score 0):

The C++ client is line-buffered by default.  This means it won't actually send the data until either a newline is pushed onto the outbound data or the buffer holding data to be sent fills beyond a certain point (system dependent).  If you want to see this in action set your `msg` string to `"Hello Server\n"`.  Your data should be sent right away.

The `flush()` command says, "send all data now, regardless of how much is in the buffer."  So you can choose to do one other the other, either call `flush()` or append a newline.  Of course if you use the newline, the Java process will receive a newline character in addition to the string, which may or may not be what you want.  Generally, when performing network operations, you want to call `flush()` whenever you're done adding things to the outbound buffer.

Comment: The string "Hello Server\n" in C++ will be shown as byte [] {'H','e'.....} or the ascii representation of the chars?

Comment: The C++ code should just send the ASCII characters for that string including the `\n` byte.